# how to set a compiler flag by enabling a feature in autoconf

Tags: autoconf, automake

I am very new to Autoconf, I would like to have a configure file that when I call: `configure --enable-gtest=yes`, such that it adds a compiler flag. The following code that I put up after searching looks as follow, but does not do the trick.

Thanks a lot

this is how my makefile looks like.

```
-include Makefile.config

SRC = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

install: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) $(DEBUGFLAG) $(OBJ) -o run

%.o:%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) $(DEBUGFLAG) -c $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

this is my configure.ac

```
AC_INIT([test], [1.7.0])

AC_PREREQ([2.59])

AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])

AC_CHECK_PROGS(CXX, [g++ c++ clang], ":")
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_SUBST(CXX)

AC_ARG_ENABLE([debug],
[  --enable-debug    Turn on debugging],
[case "${enableval}" in
  yes) debug=true ;;
  no)  debug=false ;;
  *) AC_MSG_ERROR([bad value ${enableval} for --enable-debug]) ;;
esac],[debug=false])
AM_CONDITIONAL([DEBUG], [test x$debug = xtrue])


AC_CONFIG_FILES(Makefile.config)
AC_OUTPUT
```

and my

> Makefile.config.in

```
CC = @CXX@
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++14 

if DEBUG
DBG = debug
else
DBG =
endif
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty close!  But not quite.

You're probably best off using Automake, which automates a lot of the Makefile drudgery for you.  But if you really want to avoid it, then you have to write your Makefile correctly according to what you write in `configure.ac`.

```
AM_CONDITIONAL([DEBUG], [test x$debug = xtrue])
```

This defines a couple of autoconf substitutions, like `DEBUG_TRUE` and `DEBUG_FALSE`.  The `if` form you've chosen only works in Automake, in an ordinary Makefile you have to write something like:

```
@DEBUG_TRUE@...stuff when
@DEBUG_TRUE@...true
```

Alternatively you can test the values of the substitutions using GNU make's `if` statement.

Another approach is not to use `AM_CONDITIONAL` at all but rather `AC_SUBST` the thing you want to use in your `Makefile.config.in`.